# How do I open the app settings screen with notification settings via preferences.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-preferences

How do I open the app settings screen with notification settings via preferences.xml

But my way doesn't work. And the question is how to add it to AndroidManifest. Please tell us everything in detail so that everything works. Please

> I want to open this settings menu

[image]

> This is my preferences.xml

```
<PreferenceCategory
android:title="@string/other">
<PreferenceScreen
            android:title="@string/disableNotification">
            <intent android:action="android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS"/>
        </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceCategory>
```